# Web servlet error by using html code in get method

Tags: java, servlets, web, tomcat7

I am new to web programming. I am using this simple code in my get method

```
        response.setContentType( "text/html" );
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println( "<html><head><title>Guest Book</title></head><body>" );
        out.println(" </body></html> ");
```

I am getting the below error while clicking on run on server
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECAsX.png)

Note: When i removed the html code, the servlet is working fine.Is it my Html code problem or any tomcat sevrver issue.
The servlet is in my package cs3220homework and servlet name is @WebServlet("/MainFolder").

I tried everywhere to look for the issue and i was not able to find it.If its duplicate please let me know.

Thanks for your reply
Harminder

Comment: What is `out`? `System.out` or something else?

Comment: as u can see in the code above...out is for the printwriter

Comment: Don't post a screenshot of text, post the text itself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working fine. App is named Test and Servlet class is also named Test. This is the url `http://localhost:8080/Test/Test`

```
package foo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet("/Test")
public class Test extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.setContentType( "text/html" );
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println( "<html><head><title>Guest Book</title></head><body>" );
            out.println(" </body></html> ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.It was due to the problem of eclipse which was causing the issue.I have reinstall it and now its working fine.